# Android class not found when running on some devices but not on others

Tags: java, android

When I run my app on some devices, such as a tablet that I have it works fine, no crashes.

But when I try to run it on my phone, I get an error complaining that the class definition was not found.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.output.StringBuilderWriter
```

Here is the dependencies in the gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
}
```

And the `jar` is in the `lib` folder.

Android versions:
`Phone: 4.4.2`
`Tablet: 5.1.1`

SDK Setup:
`compileSdkVersion: 25`
`minSdkVersion: 15`
`targetSdkVersion: 24`

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Does your phone and tablet have the same Android version?

Comment: Why do you need a jar file? `compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.4'`

Comment: @cricket_007 Thats the way it was when I inherited the project, should I get rid of it?

Comment: @pleft Updated question with different versions

Comment: It is likely to work better if you use the dependency directly, but go ahead and try it (also remove the jar file from the libs folder)

Comment: Is your phone's api level equal to or higher than the minimum api level of your app?

Comment: I would say to completely remove the app from both tablet and phone and try installing it again. Maybe its a cache thing.

Comment: @BrettJeffreson Its high enough, included SDK Setup in gradle to the original question

Comment: You should be able to accept the existing answer. Or answer below. The question section should only be a question

Answer (score 0):

> Does anybody have any ideas

You should add apache commons directly to your project:

```
compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.5"
```

Comment: `Failed to resolve: org.apache.commons:commons-io:2.5`

Comment: Do I need to add another repository to resolve this?

Comment: `2.5` should be available on jCenter or Maven central. Not sure why you put the `+`

Comment: Due to lazyness. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the real issue was with `multiDexing`

I added this to the `defaultConfig`:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

And included this to my `dependencies`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```