# SQLiteAssetHelper utils not found

Tags: java, android

I had another post earlier about my project having a `class not found exception` for `IOUtils`. I fixed that, and now my project is crashing again.

Previous post: [Android class not found when running on some devices but not on others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679873/android-class-not-found-when-running-on-some-devices-but-not-on-others)

Giving me this stack trace now:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.Utils
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:455)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
    at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
    at com.testing.data.AppDatabase.<init>(AppDatabase.java:87)
    at com.testing.data.AppDatabase.getInstance(AppDatabase.java:70)
```

It works when I try to run it on my tablet, and it crashes when I try to run it on my phone:

Here is the setup:

```
Android versions:
`Phone: 4.4.2`
`Tablet: 5.1.1`

SDK Setup:
`compileSdkVersion: 25`
`minSdkVersion: 15`
`targetSdkVersion: 24`
```

Could there possibly something conflicting? Seems unlikely, but they are both Util classes that are not being found.

Grade as requested:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.+'
    compile 'com.qozix:tileview:2.2.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
    compile 'org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:4.0.4'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testing.base"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I see that `SQLiteAssetHelper` seems to be a 3rd party library.

Comment: @Jonathan727 Yes it is. Its included in my gradle file, and I can see the Library AND the `missing` util class in the `External Libraries` folder, after gradle runs a build. Not sure why its not found at run time.

Comment: are you running proguard/minify at all?

Comment: Updated question to include gradle, see proguard there also.

Comment: I'm suspect the multiDex could contribute to an issue like this.